# Size of value affecting computation time?

Tags: java, programming-languages, integer, theory

Say I have a Java program such:

```
//case1
Long first = 1;
Long second = 1;
Long third = first - second;

//case2
Long first = Long.MAX_VALUE;
Long second = 100000L;
Long third = first - second;
```

Those two cases should have the exact same execution time and overhead shouldn't they? The actual operation is performed on every bit in the Long right, regardless of the value contained within it, right?

If my assumption is true,is there any language where this is NOT the case?

EDIT: The case that prompted this is a 16 bit PIC we are using at work ( C code), that calculates averages over a variable amount of time.  After the answers below from M S and Thom, I now understand that it IS possible to introduce a bug this way, since the PIC is computing mission critical information, on a time-sensitive basis.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: The literal values need to be `long` (`1L`, etc.) for this to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say is true in Java — the operations execute in a time that is independent of the values. In some languages (such as Lisp), if the value exceeds the maximum legal value for the data type, execution automatically switches to use a "big integer" package, which slows the execution down considerably.

**EDIT**
There is a slight difference between the first and second cases: the value `1` is special (as is 0). The byte code for

```
Long first=1L;
```

is:

```
lconst_1
invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
astore_1
```

whereas if the constant is (say) 2L, one gets this byte code:

```
ldc2_w  #3; //long 2l
invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
astore_2
```

Since `lconst_1` runs faster than `ldc2_w`, there is a slight time difference between cases 1 and 2.

Comment: That is nice to know about Lisp.  these are the subtle kinds of things that can bite you when you transfer languages.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any, but I could envision a language which simply has an "integer" data type that sizes the integer as needed, causing small numbers to be faster than large numbers. (Consider Java's `BigInteger` class).

As for the code you have up there, no those will be exactly the same performance with the *slight* exception that becuase you're using `Long` instead of `long` you will get a pre-made `Long` for `first` and `second` while the others must be created in the second example.

If you used values like `200` and `201` in your first example and `10000000000` and `100000000001` in your second, they would be identical.

Comment: good catch.  I goofed on the L/l bit.  Nice distinction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its not depend on language, rather it depends on the underlying hardware. The register size and the data bus width.

For eg, if the Long.MAX_VALUE is greater that 16bits in a 16 bit machine, it requires 2 cycles to load data in to the memory hence case 1 and case 2 will have different execution time.

usually these max values is set in according with the machine bit size

Comment: Regarding bus width, cycle counts, etc.: this will depend on the data type being loaded, not the values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an answer, but on a 32 bit computer, 64 bit values are not thread safe because it must place half the value in a register and calculate, then the other half. There might be an optimization that would ignore the all zeroes part of the value and would therefore be faster for smaller numbers.

Comment: Even 32 bit values are not necessarily thread-safe on a 32 bit computer. It can depend on the alignment of the 32 bits stored in memory. In Java, it's implementation specific: _"Java virtual machines are free to perform writes to long and double values atomically or in two parts."_ ([Java Language Specification §17.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.7))